# What's the word for when you excessively advertise something?

Tags: single-word-requests

What the exact word when you excessively advertise something? A bit like a stereotype but not really. kind of like social pressure.

Comment: This tag is for questions seeking a single word that fits a meaning. To ensure your question is not closed as off-topic, please be specific about the intended use of the word. YOU MUST INCLUDE A SAMPLE SENTENCE demonstrating how the word would be used.

Answer (score 3):

Are you thinking of 'hype'? Meaning excited talk or excessive attention to something new:

e.g. there is a lot of hype surrounding the iPhone X these days.

[Cambridge dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/hype) defines it as:

> a situation in which something is advertised and discussed in newspapers, on television, etc. a lot in order to attract everyone's interest:
>
> *media hype*
>
> *There's been a lot of hype around/surrounding his latest film.*
>
> *I've been put off reading the book by all the hype.*

Comment: It would be an even better answer if you could also include a dictionary link.

Answer (score 2):

To **tout** something is to repeatedly and insistently advertise something.

From Cambridge:

> to advertise, talk about, or praise something or someone repeatedly, especially as a way of encouraging people to like, accept, or buy something:

You might also consider **making a hard sell**, or if you think there may be some shenanigans whereby someone is promoting something as if they were a real customer, when in fact they stand to benefit from further sales, you might call that person a **shill**, or say that they **shill for** the product.

From Cambridge:

> someone who helps another person to persuade people to buy something, especially by pretending to be a satisfied customer